# Index sequence adding arrays together

Tags: c++, c++20

I've been trying to make use of `std::index_sequence`, I've been trying to get this piece of code to work any help or pointers?

```
template <typename tty,
          std::size_t ssz,
          typename is = std::make_index_sequence<std::min(sz, ssz)>>    
auto operator + (ss::array_helper<tty, ssz> right) const
{
    auto ret = *this;

    [ = ] ( auto s ) {
        [] ( ty& l , tty& r ) { l += r; } 
            ( ret [ is ] , right [ is ] )...;
    } ( is { } );

    return ret;
};
```

Comment: What is `sz` here?

Comment: ty is type of current array and sz is sizeof current array, tty is type of array on rightside of operator, and ssz is sizeof rightside array of operator. Im trying to only add each index together with std::index_sequence but only allowing for the minimum size to be added together.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question so that it shows a [mre]? C++ syntax is quite complicated. Most people who would be inclined to answer and help you would want to double-check that their answer actually compiles and works. As shown, this is pretty much impossible since the shown code is using types and namespaces that are not defined, and are mostly a big mystery as to what they are. Before posting their first question on stackoverflow.com, everyone should take the [tour], read the [help], understand all the requirements for a [mre] and [ask] questions here.

Comment: Well thats the problem, I can't figure out how to make it compile. I don't know what to change in order to make it correct. I understand how that'd contribute to getting help faster but I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. I never work with index sequences so.

Comment: Make it "correct" how? What is it trying to do, and how are you trying to use it? Those are what isn't clear here. Write out the whole code that you're trying to make "correct", including how you *use this*.

Comment: Well, nobody is asking you "how to make it compile". You are being asked to shown a [mre] where everything would compile, except for the part in question. The best way to get help on Stackoverflow is to make it as easy as possible for others to reproduce your question ***by themselves***. In its current form, nobody can do that, since nobody has any clue what these mysterious `ss::array_helper` types are, or which parameters the template gets instantiated with. Have you taken Stackoverflow's [tour] yet, read the [help], and learned [ask] questions? If not, why not?

Comment: @Valena: We don't ask a lot, just having `template<typename T, std::size_t  sz> struct array_helper { /* your operator + */ T& operator[](std::size_t); };` so ech of us don't have fill blank part.

Comment: *"It's very easy to understand what's going on in the code provided, it's an operator for adding right side `ss::array_helper` to the current `ss::array_helper`"* You consider that as obvious. Wonder how you would understand if I say something like, solution is easy, parameterize your class with `std::index_sequence` instead of `size`, and it is solved.

Comment: Why remove your code from the question?

Comment: Since there are many meta comments here, not related to the question or a possible solution, I will add also one meta comment. We should try to reduce the consequences of the Dunning Kruger effect and try to refrain from the urge to lecture newbies regarding MRE, rubber ducks and the usage of debuggers. Instead, we should concentrate our activities to help. Very obviously, the OP wants to add different size arrays using ````std::make_index_sequence````. I guess this is not that difficult to spot. Although I am just a humble low-rep guy, I was able to provide some answer . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting question. Jarod42 showed already the solution using C++20. But, in C++17 we do not have templated lambdas.

In order for you to have a C++17 solution, I will present an implementation that uses a templated member function for the addition.

Since I do not know your definition for data type `array_helper`, I use an **example-only** version and derive simply from `std::array`, which you should normally not do. I do it here just for demo purposes.

The templated member function can be defined as expected:

```
    // Templated function that performs the addition
    template <typename TRight, size_t SizeRight, size_t ... indices>
    auto add(array_helper<T, Size>& left, array_helper<TRight, SizeRight>& right, std::index_sequence<indices...>) {
        array_helper<T, Size> result{};
        ((result[indices] = left[indices] + right[indices]), ...);
        return result;
    };
```

There is no surprise. A straightforward implementation. And this we will call in the overwritten '+' operator.

---

The beauty of it is that we can now add arrays of different type and length.

---

All this leads to an easy to understand and somehow simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <typename T, const size_t Size, size_t ... Is>
struct array_helper : public std::array<T,Size> {

    // Templated function that performs the addition
    template <typename TRight, size_t SizeRight, size_t ... indices>
    auto add(array_helper<T, Size>& left, array_helper<TRight, SizeRight>& right, std::index_sequence<indices...>) {
        array_helper<T, Size> result{};
        ((result[indices] = left[indices] + right[indices]), ...);
        return result;
    };

    // Override operator + for array_helper
    template <typename TOther, size_t SizeOther>
    auto operator + (array_helper<TOther, SizeOther>& other) {

        // Call templated member function
        return add(*this, other, std::make_index_sequence<std::min(SizeOther, Size)>{});
    }
};

int main() {
    // Some test variables
    array_helper<char, 4> array1{ 'a','b','c','d'  };
    array_helper<int, 3> array2{ 1,2,3 };
    
    // Call '+' operator
    auto array3 = array1 + array2;

    // Show debug output
    std::copy(array1.begin(), array1.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, "\n")); std::cout << '\n';
    std::copy(array2.begin(), array2.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n")); std::cout << '\n';
    std::copy(array3.begin(), array3.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, "\n")); std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

---

Compiled using **C++17.**

Works with

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.8.2
- clang 11.0.0 X86-64
- gcc 10.2 X86-64

Comment: would just like you to know, you're an amazing person. thanks for coming in the discussion and having a positive attitude even if I couldn't articulate it correctly. Not even that, you also contributed to the conversation and had something useful to say. Thank you, Armin for president.

Answer (score 2):

usage of `std::index_sequence` is to expand it in its variadic form:

```
[&] template <std::size_t ... Is> (std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    ((res[Is] += rhs[Is]), ...);
} (std::make_index_sequence<std::min(sz, ssz)>{});
```

Comment: I just want you to know, you're a legend. You didn't derail my question, straight to the point and provided a very elegant solution to my problem. I understand my question wasn't really well formed but I was just trying to give a general gist. Thanks for being kind and providing a well written solution.

Comment: @Valena "I understand my question wasn't really well formed" - but you could've taken (and still can take) the time to _improve_ your question to make it clear what you are asking. Instead, you invested that time in being hostile towards people who wanted to help but could not due to the low quality of the question.